# How do I use escape caracter in SQL to query with LIKE? (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, escaping

Trying but failing to use `LIKE` in my `Query`.

This works fine, using `?` and `=`:

```
def read_part_of_database(table_column, user_query):
    c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table" 
            "WHERE {} = ? ORDER BY time_start".format(table_column), [(user_query)])
    for row in c_lime.fetchall():
        print(row)
```

But with this, the user needs to input the exact and full `query` as it is presented in the `database`. So instead I want to use `LIKE`. I have tried the following, but none of it seems to work:

```
c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} LIKE %s" 
        "ORDER BY time_start".format(table_column), ["%" + user_query + "%"])
```

This gives me error: 
    `c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} LIKE %s ORDER BY time_start".format(table_column), ["%" + user_query + "%"])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error`

I have tried a few more variations of this, taken from `SO` and other sources, but none of it seems to work. Is there something I'm doing wrong with the escape `%s`?

`user_query` is, when using `= ?`, a date: `2/14/2015 1:00:00 PM` and when using `LIKE` I take a part of that: `2/14/2015`

Comment: A percent symbol ("%") in the LIKE pattern matches any sequence of zero or more characters in the string. Therefore, you can't use `%s` string substitution within a `LIKE ...` statement.

Comment: It worked for me like this: `LIKE '%{}'` and pass your user query in `.format()`.

Comment: @Julia, hmm, still not getting it right. This is what I wrote: `("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} LIKE '%{}' ORDER BY time_start".format(table_column, [user_query]))`

Comment: Did you pass `user_query` as a list or is it a typo?

Comment: Hey, yeah, now it worked! Thanks for taking the time @Julia, really nice of your :) About the brackets, I used them previously in my query that had `= ?`. It didn't without it. New to Python, so not sure what's up with that :/

Comment: @Julia, Oh, and post a real answer if you want me to mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use % character in a query with LIKE, enclose it in single quotation marks:

```
 c_lime.execute("""SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} LIKE '%{}' 
                   ORDER BY time_start""".format(table_column, user_query))
```